# Why the parent div still keeps the width of its child image original width?

Tags: html, css, image

I have several divs and an image like this

```
<div class="show-image">
    <div class="image-info-box">
        <div class="info-content">test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img class="img-box" src="image.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css file is:

```
.show-image {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.img-box {
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 75%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

.image-container {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto;
}

.image-info-box {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.info-content {
    float: center;
}
```

I want the image has its 75% width, so I set the width of img-box class to 75% (say the image width is 1008px for example, thus the img-box is with width 756px). The problem is why the div with class image-container still keeps the original image width, i.e. 1008px for the example. How can the image-container fits its width to the img-box?

Comment: `div` is block element by default, and have, by default, `width: 100%;` as all block elements. Base CSS behavior.

Comment: so how can I set the parent div fits to the child image width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the limitation width to the parent, not in child. So that it will work as what you expected.

```
.image-container {
display: inline-block;  
width:75%;
}

.image-info-box {
width: 100%;
padding-top: 30px;
text-align: center;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/er4L467h/)

Comment: Yes it works for the image-container div, but the show-image div, i.e. the root div, is still the original width, even if I set its width to 75%.

Answer (score 0):

with using only div(without image tag) you can do like this.

```
<div class="show-image">
    <div class="image-info-box">
        <div class="info-content">test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

Use this CSS.

```
.image-container {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto;
    background: url('Hopetoun_falls.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```